# Sum rows after comparing one row with multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that will be `a` and `b`. I want to compare `number` in `a` to `number` in `b` where they share an ID. `a` has a single row, while `b` has multiple. If the sum of `b` is less than `a`, then that row of `a` should be added to the total sum, otherwise it should be skipped.

```
Table a
ID  Number
4   50
5   60
6   70

Table b
ID  Number  SharedID
1   30      4
2   25      4
3   50      5
4   5       5
5   30      6
6   10      6
```

Using that example: b 1 and 2 are greater than a 4, so it wouldn't be counted. b 3 and 4 are less than a 5 so it would count. b 5 and 6 are less than a 6, so it would count. The total should be 130.

I'm having trouble with doing a comparison of one row to multiple and then only summing some of the numbers.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: The expected output is `130` via a summing of the successful rows.

Comment: The goal is a single result that would probably use `SUM(Number) AS whatever`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
select sum(Number)
from a
where Number > (select sum(Number) from b where b.SharedID = a.ID)
```

Comment: Wow, this answer is so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT SUM(a.Number)
FROM a INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT b.SharedID, SUM(b.Number) AS theSum
    FROM b
    GROUP BY b.SharedID
) t
ON a.ID = t.SharedID
WHERE t.theSum < a.Number
```

The conceptually easiest option is to create a temporary table containing the sums of Table b, and then to `JOIN` that back to Table a.  The `WHERE` clause restricts your total to only a `Number` values which are greater than the b sum.

Comment: It works and it's the kind of complicated answer I expected to need, but Giorgi's solution is so simple.

Comment: @Rhyono I agree that his answer is simple, but it is harder to understand what it is doing.  I guess it's a matter of taste.  In this, Giorgi tasted better than I did.

Comment: I think it's a matter of programming style; I understand both of your answers, but his is more of a native language and yours is more secondary, for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(number) from(
select case when(aa.number>(select SUM(bb.number)
 from bb where bb.sharedid=aa.id))then aa.number else 0 end as number  from aa )abc
```

This should do the trick